# How to make a Macro-Free backup copy of a Word Document using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Macro-Enabled word document which I want to make a Macro-Free Backup Copy of my document else where on the network every time I press a certain commandbutton on my userform. I Don't want to use ".SaveAs2" because I still want to be in Macro-Enabled document after I hitting commandbutton.

In Excel we had this workaround which you could copy all sheets using "sheets.copy" on macro-enabled excel file and then save newly created workbook (which is now a macro-free workbook) anywhere you want using "ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs" method.

Comment: Consider using a macro-enabled template and using it as a document template. That will automatically create a macro-free new document, still attached to your template and able to use your userform. If needed, you could attach the normal template when you conclude your userform. The user will then need to assign a name to the new document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub Word_CopyFileBasedOnActiveDocument()
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document: Set wDoc = ActiveDocument
    Dim wTmp As Word.Document

    ' Create a new document based on the active document
    Set wTmp = Application.Documents.Add(Template:=wDoc.FullName, Visible:=False)
    
    ' Save as non macro enabled
    wTmp.SaveAs2 Filename:=wDoc.Path & "\newFile.doc", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
    
    ' Close file
    wTmp.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Elio. Your solution works fine.